# Google Calendar Date String to JS Date Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm currently dealing with the Google Calendar API and I get the date's as following string back :

```
"2020-04-26T05:30:00+02:00"
```

(Timezone "Europe/Berlin")

I want to store this date in this format :

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ
```

so the common date format in js.

But whenever I try to save the upper date as a JS Date Object it subtracts my timezone and store it like this:

```
 "2020-04-26T03:30:00.000Z"
```

Is there a way to ignore the timezone and keep the Date Object in the locale time so like this:

```
 "2020-04-26T05:30:00.000Z"
```

I tried several things with moment.js but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can convert the string to a Date object and create a new string object i nthe local timezone by subtracting the offset.*

#### Code:

```js
var response = "2020-04-26T05:30:00+02:00";
var responseDate = new Date(response);
var dateObj = new Date(responseDate.getTime()
                       - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000).toISOString();
```

#### References:

- [`Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()` - JavaSctipt | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)